# Find all values of a and b that make the following function differentiable for all values of x

Tags: derivatives

**Problem**
Find all values of $a$ and $b$ that make the following function differentiable for all values of $x$:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 \arctan(ax+b), x<0\\
 \pi/4e^{\sin(bx)}, x \geq 0\\   
\end{cases}  
$$

I thought I had this question figured out but it started to get more complicated than I think it should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to match the function at 0 and then evaluate the right and left hand limits for the derivatives and match these

$\arctan(b) =  \frac{\pi}{4}$ implies that $b = 1$.

$\frac{a}{1+(ax+b)^2} = \frac{a}{1+1} $ set equal to $ \frac{\pi}{4}b  =\frac{\pi}{4}$. 
So $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thanks so much, I was definitely over thinking that one